# PrintWriter append method not appending

Tags: java, printwriter

The following method only writes out the latest item I have added, it does not append to previous entries. What am I doing wrong?

```
public void addNew() {
    try {
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new File("persons.txt"));
        int id = Integer.parseInt(jTextField.getText());
        String name = jTextField1.getText();
        String surname = jTextField2.getText();
        Person p = new Person(id,name,surname);
        pw.append(p.toString());
        pw.append("sdf");
        pw.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {...}
}
```

Answer (score 107, accepted):

The fact that `PrintWriter`'s method is called `append()` doesn't mean that it changes  mode of the file being opened.

You need to open file in append mode as well:

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(
    new File("persons.txt"), 
    true /* append = true */));
```

Also note that file will be written in system default encoding. It's not always desired and may cause interoperability problems, you may want to specify file encoding explicitly.

Comment: This is like awakening the sleeping thread, so sorry for that. But i have a doubt. how would i do append operation in file if i am given only File object, and i am not allowed to use Stream classes( e.g FileOutputStream and so on). What i am allowed is :    Printwriter pw = new PrintWriter(file);  :  I tried append(), write(), print(). is there any readymade method for appending in this scenario.

Comment: As a clarification, the 'append()' method of PrintWriter refers to the fact that it is appending to the Writer i.e itself i.e it's own outputstream, and not to the file.

Comment: And with reference to @user1707035's question, no, it looks like you can't use a PrintWriter to append without constructing it with an OutputStream object. This is because the PrintWriter open the stream at the time of it's instantiation, and the only constructors that support File or filename as an argument open the File by internally constructing an OutputStream object without the 'append' parameter. Reference (docs): https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter(java.io.File)

Answer (score 19):

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(new File("persons.txt"),true));
```

The `true` is the append flag. See [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html).

Answer (score 14):

IMHO the accepted answer does not consider the fact that the intention is to write characters.

From the [`FileOutputStream` docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html), you use `FileOutputStream` when you want to print bytes.

> FileOutputStream is meant for writing streams of raw bytes such as
> image data. For writing streams of characters, consider using
> FileWriter.

Besides, from the [`BufferedWriter` docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html):

> Unless prompt output is required, it is advisable to wrap a
> BufferedWriter around any Writer whose write() operations may be
> costly, such as FileWriters and OutputStreamWriters.

Finally, the answer would be the following (as mentioned [in this other StackOverFlow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15053443/1814970)):

> ```
> PrintWriter out = null;
> try {
>     out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("writePath", true)));
>     out.println("the text");
> }catch (IOException e) {
>     System.err.println(e);
> }finally{
>     if(out != null){
>         out.close();
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Also, as of Java 7, you can use a try-with-resources statement. No
> finally block is required for closing the declared resource(s) because
> it is handled automatically, and is also less verbose:
>
> ```
> try(PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("writePath", true)))) {
>     out.println("the text");
> }catch (IOException e) {
>     System.err.println(e);
> }
> ```

Answer (score 13):

Open the file in append mode, as with the following code:

```
 PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(new File("persons.txt"), true));
```

Answer (score 4):

You need not to double buffering as shown in all other answers.
You can simply do

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("persons.txt",true));
```