# PrintWriter to append data if file exist

Tags: java, fileoutputstream, printwriter

I have a savegame file called `mysave.sav` and I want to add data to this file if the file already exists. If the file doesn't exists, I want to create the file and then add the data.

Adding data works fine. But appending data overwrites existing data. I followed the instructions of axtavt here ([PrintWriter append method not appending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8210616/printwriter-append-method-not-appending)).

```
    String savestr = "mysave.sav"; 
    File f = new File(savestr);
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(savestr);

    if ( f.exists() && !f.isDirectory() ) {
        out = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(new File(savestr), true));
        out.append(mapstring);
        out.close();
    }
    else {
        out.println(mapstring);
        out.close();
    }
```

where `mapstring` is the string I want to append. Can you help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Once you call `PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(savestr);` the file is created if doesn't exist hence first check for file existence then initialize it.

As mentioned in it's [Constructor Docmentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter%28java.lang.String%29) as well that says:

> If the file exists then it will be truncated to zero size; otherwise, a new file will be created.

Since file is created before calling `f.exists()` hence it will return `true` always and `ìf` block is never executed at all.

Sample code:

```
String savestr = "mysave.sav"; 
File f = new File(savestr);

PrintWriter out = null;
if ( f.exists() && !f.isDirectory() ) {
    out = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(new File(savestr), true));
}
else {
    out = new PrintWriter(savestr);
}
out.append(mapstring);
out.close();
```

For better resource handling use [`Java 7 - The try-with-resources Statement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Comment: Thank you, this works if I leave out the first line of the if block (out = new PrinterWriter(savestr)). I don't know if I'm allowed to edit your answer.

Comment: @pilky02 by mistake added. you are free to edit it. I am more than happy if you edit it.

Comment: Thanks for edit. please follow last link that might help you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use BufferedWriter:

```
    System.out.println("Enter text to input:  ");
    String textToAppend = input.nextLine();
 
    //Set true for append mode

    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
    new FileWriter("C:\\folder 1\\filename.txt", true));    

    writer.write(textToAppend);
    writer.close();
```