# java FileWriter append

Tags: java, file

If you are using a FileWriter in append mode (i.e append set to true in the constructor) is there any easy way of determining if you are appending to an existing file or writing to a new file?

Clearly you could try reading the file first but I wonder if there a one liner to know whether you are creating the file or not?

Thanks

Comment: `File.exists()` and `File.isFile()`

Comment: This [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24982744/printwriter-to-append-data-if-file-exist/24982850#24982850) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Before initializing the `FileWriter` you can use `file.exists()` (which returns a boolean) to see if the file exists. Then you can do other checks such as `file.isFile()` and `!file.isDirectory()` to make sure that these are files you can write to.

Comment: Thanks - not quite a one liner but almost.

Comment: Well you can always use `&&` to join together.