# Print To File in Java

Tags: java, file

i have a problem in my java exercise.
i need to print a multiply contact information to a file, but when i print more then 1 contact, only 1 contact is displayed in the file.. 
i tried to debug that but i cant find any mistake
i will put the code of my classes here:

**This is Demo Class which i run the code from**

```
public class Demo {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Insert number of Contacts:");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int val = scanner.nextInt();
    Contact[] contacts = new Contact[val];

    for(int i = 0 ; i < val; i++) {
        System.out.println("Contact #"+(i+1));
        System.out.print("Owner: \n");
            String owner = scanner.next();
        System.out.print("Phone number: \n");
            String phoneNum = scanner.next();

        System.out.print("Please Select Group:\n"
                + "1 For FRIENDS,\n" + 
                "2 For FAMILY,\n" + 
                "3 For WORK,\n" + 
                "4 For OTHERS");
        int enumNum = scanner.nextInt();
        Group group;

        switch(enumNum) {       
        case 1:
            group=Group.FRIENDS;
            break;
        case 2:
            group=Group.FAMILY;
            break;
        case 3:
            group=Group.WORK;
            break;
        default:
            group=Group.OTHERS;     
        }//switch end

        contacts[i] = new Contact(owner,phoneNum,group);

    }//loop end
    System.out.println("Insert File name");
    String fileName = scanner.next();
    File f=null;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < val; i++) {
        if(i==0) {
            f = new File(fileName);
            contacts[0].Save(fileName);
        }
        else {

            contacts[i].Save(f);        
        }

    }

}
```

}

This is Contact Class:

```
enum Group {
FRIENDS,
FAMILY,
WORK,
OTHERS
```

};
public class Contact {

```
private String phoneNumber,owner;
private Group group;
PrintWriter pw = null;


  public Contact(String owner ,String phoneNumber,Group group) {
      setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
      setOwner(owner);
      setGroup(group);
  }

  public Contact(String fileName) {
      File file = new File(fileName+".txt");


      try {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
         phoneNumber=scanner.nextLine();
         owner=scanner.nextLine();
         String str=scanner.nextLine();
         group = Group.valueOf(str);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
      catch(Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }

  }

  public Contact(File file) {

      try {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
         phoneNumber=scanner.nextLine();
         owner=scanner.nextLine();
         String str=scanner.nextLine();
         group = Group.valueOf(str);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
      catch(Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }

  }

public String getPhoneNumber() {
    return phoneNumber;
}

public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}

public String getOwner() {
    return owner;
}

public void setOwner(String owner) {
    this.owner = owner;
}
public Group getGroup() {
    return group;
}
public void setGroup(Group group) {
    this.group = group;
}   
public void Save(String fileName) {

    File f = new File(fileName+".txt");

    try {
        if(f.createNewFile()) {
            System.out.println("File created");
            pw = new PrintWriter(f); //יצירת מדפסת לקובץ    
            pw.println(phoneNumber+"\n"+owner+"\n"+group+"\n\n\n");

        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    pw.close();

}

public void Save(File f) {



    PrintWriter pw=null;
    try {
        pw = new PrintWriter(f);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    pw.println(phoneNumber+"\n"+owner+"\n"+group);
    pw.close();

}   

public String toString() {
    return phoneNumber+"\n"+owner+"\n"+group;


}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you create `PrintWriter` the file is being overwritten. Since you create a new `PrintWriter` for each contact, the file contains only the last contact information. What you should do is to create `PrintWriter` only once and use it for all contacts.

Firstly, let's create a new `save` method with such signature:

```
public void save(PrintWriter writer)
```

I have also used the lowercase name of the method due to [Java naming convention](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html).

Now the implementation of `save` method will look like this:

```
writer.println(phoneNumber);
writer.println(owner);
writer.println(group + "\n\n\n");
```

Then we should replace the usage of `Save` method with the new one. Here is your code:

```
String fileName = scanner.next();
File f = null;
for (int i = 0; i < val; i++) {
    if(i == 0) {
        f = new File(fileName);
        contacts[0].Save(fileName);
    } else {
        contacts[i].Save(f);        
    }
}
```

In order to fix the issue we can change it like this:

```
String fileName = scanner.next();
File file = new File(fileName);
try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(file)) {
    for (int i = 0; i < val; i++) {
        contacts[i].save(writer);
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I have also used [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) which closes the `PrintWriter` automatically.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintWriter.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.io.File)) of the constructor of `PrintWriter`:

> `public PrintWriter​(File file)`
> Parameters: `file` - The file to use as the destination of this writer. If the file exists then it will be truncated to zero size; otherwise, a new file will be created. The output will be written to the file and is buffered.

In the `Save` function you create a `PrintWriter` everytime. So everytime the file is truncated, and then you lose the contact you saved before.

Comment: There is 2 Save methods(One-that gets a String, two- that gets a File), Which one is the wrong one?

Comment: Yes, because from the second contact you call the second `Save` function. Anyway, the constructor with the filename as parameter has the same behaviour. You can check its Javadoce [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintWriter.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String))

Comment: Excuse me for being a little ignorant, i cant seem to find the exact line to remove, can u mark this out for me please?

Comment: There's no line to remove. You have to change the way you use the PrintWriter. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8210616/printwriter-append-method-not-appending).

Answer (score 0):

Since File I/O classes in java use [Decorator Design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern), you can use a `FileWriter` to take advantage of **appending** to a file. So you can use this code for `Save()` method :

```
public void Save(String fileName) {

File f = new File(fileName+".txt");

try {

        //System.out.println("File created");  You don't need to create new file.
        FileWriter fw=new FileWriter(f,true):// second argument enables append mode

        pw = new PrintWriter(fw); //יצירת מדפסת לקובץ    
        pw.println(phoneNumber+"\n"+owner+"\n"+group+"\n\n\n");

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
pw.close();

}
```